# How is there full employment level at equilibrium level according to Keynesian theory(AD-AS approach)?

Tags: macroeconomics, unemployment, new-keynesian-economics, keynesian-economics, keynes

According to Keynesian theory :-

Equilibrium level is the point at which Aggregate Demand curve intersects Aggregate Supply curve .
And this point is termed as Full Employment Level

How do we interpret that this is level of full employment ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is 'full employment' synonymous with 'the natural rate of unemployment'?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/5821/is-full-employment-synonymous-with-the-natural-rate-of-unemployment)